# Compiling ffmpeg for android using cygwin-x86

Tags: android, android-ndk, ffmpeg

I'd like to test ijkplayer (android) project.
During compiling ffmpeg libs (./compile-ffmpeg.sh) usin Cygwin in WIN7 environment I faced the following error message:

"build on CYGWIN_NT-6.1 x86_64
 Host system 'cygwin-x86' is not supported by the source NDK!
 Try --system= with one of: windows-x86_64"

The suggested 'system' command doesn't solve the problem.
Axtually I use android-ndk-r10c

If I try the same process using MINGW32 I get a lot of syntax error.
Please help!

Comment: you need to configure first to use toolchain. Then you can compile for android project.